# Namespace and Assembly

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015

I found something which gave me thinking.

I added `using System.Windows;` to my `.cs` file because I wanted tu use

```
DependencyObject foo
```

and the name was not recognized even when i change it on:

```
System.Windows.DependencyObject foo
```

To make first code work I had to add the assembly to my project.

So why we have `using` if we have to add assembly to project? I mean what is the mechanism behind that?

Comment: The *using* directive merely is helpful to avoid having to type the full type name in your source code.  And only applies to the namespace name, not the assembly name.  You can't use what you don't reference, you have to tell the compiler where it comes from.  VS2015 makes it easy with the lightbulb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Using` does not add the Assemblies for you. And you can only use the assemblies that are referenced in your project.

When you create a dot net project, if automatically add some assemblies for you, and if you need use any other assembly out of of them you need to add them. It is simply not feasible to add all the references in the world at first place.

**Consider an analogy**, You are a chef and you need to prepare some dish. You can only prepare dish **using** the items that are there in your kitchen, if you need some other ingredient which is not there, you get it from store and **use** it then. Imagine having all the ingredients of the world right in your kitchen!!

Comment: Yeah i see it... Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You must add the assembly to be able to use the classes inside of that assembly.  Once you've added the assembly to your project, if you don't add the using statement, then you must always refer to the class in that assembly using the fully qualified name, e.g. System.Windows.DependencyObject.  Once you add the using statement, you can refer to the class using just its class name, e.g. DependencyObject.  In other words, the using statement is just there to provide a shorter way of refering to the class.

Answer (score 0):

There are difference between those two.
Imagine you have the following code in `File1.cs:`

```
// File1.cs
using System;
namespace Outer.Inner
{
    class Foo
    {
        static void Bar()
        {
            double d = Math.PI;
        }
    }
}
```

Now imagine that someone adds another file `(File2.cs)` to the project that looks like this:

```
// File2.cs
namespace Outer
{
    class Math
    {
    }
}
```

The compiler searches Outer before looking at those using statements outside the namespace, so it finds Outer.Math instead of System.Math. Unfortunately (or perhaps fortunately?), Outer.Math has no PI member, so File1 is now broken.

This changes if you put the using inside your namespace declaration, as follows:

```
// File1b.cs
namespace Outer.Inner
{
    using System;
    class Foo
    {
        static void Bar()
        {
            double d = Math.PI;
        }
    }
}
```

Now the compiler searches System before searching Outer, finds System.Math, and all is well.

Some would argue that Math might be a bad name for a user-defined class, since there's already one in System; the point here is just that there is a difference, and it affects the maintainability of your code.

It's also interesting to note what happens if Foo is in namespace Outer, rather than Outer.Inner. In that case, adding Outer.Math in File2 breaks File1 regardless of where the using goes. This implies that the compiler searches the innermost enclosing namespace before it looks at any using statements.